# Flutter: How do I change the image size in my appbar?

Tags: flutter

I am new to `Flutter`. I am creating a basic Flutter app. This is my code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
            title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children:[
                    const Image(image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'), fit:BoxFit.fitHeight,),
                    Text(
                        widget.title
                    ),
                ]
            )
         ),
      );
  }
}
```

This is the output image:

[image]

The image is so big, how do I scale it so that it fits in the appbar?

Comment: instead of this use sliver widgets for this type of scenario

Comment: I think you can put `kToolbarHeight` as image height

Comment: This is height of appBar: `AppBar().preferredSize.height`. Try to set the height of `Image` widget equal to this height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your image height instead of app bar preferred height

```
AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
             Image(
              image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
            ),
            Text(widget.title),
          ],
        ),
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have a little space between the `image` and the `title`?

Comment: you may use sizedbox with width between image and title